# Android Studio ImageView

Tags: android, android-studio, resize, android-imageview

I'm trying to create, resize and add an imageView and I've been looking for a solution to this all over but nothing works properly, every time I set any kind of Param the image doesn't appear anymore or the app crashes, I'm using Android Studio 1.0.1 and this are the methods I've tried:

This one the image disapear

```
TableRow tableInfoCont = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.simpleAvatar);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams imgPar = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
imgPar.width = 50;
imgPar.height = 50;
imgPar.setMargins(5,5,5,5);

imageView.setLayoutParams(imgPar);
tableInfoCont.addView(imageView);
```

This one the image disapear

```
TableRow tableInfoCont = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.simpleAvatar);

FrameLayout.LayoutParams imgPar = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
imgPar.width = 50;
imgPar.height = 50;
imgPar.setMargins(5,5,5,5);

imageView.setLayoutParams(imgPar);
tableInfoCont.addView(imageView);
```

This one the app crashes

```
TableRow tableInfoCont = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.simpleAvatar);

ViewGroup.LayoutParams imgPar = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
imgPar.width = 50;
imgPar.height = 50;
//imgPar.setMargins(5,5,5,5); //not possible to set margin

imageView.setLayoutParams(imgPar);
tableInfoCont.addView(imageView);
```

This one the app crashes

```
TableRow tableInfoCont = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.simpleAvatar);

imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 50;
imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 50;

tableInfoCont.addView(imageView);
```

That is it, tryed all this methods... Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that is discouraged to create Layout in code.

Also try to let a simple ImageView show up first before you go with a TableView.

Try this code :

```
TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.simpleAvatar);
tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
tableRow.addView(imageView);
tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
setContentView(tableLayout);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm trying to build a forum post where you have the avatar of the user, date of the post and the post message, that is why I have to create layout in code, Is there a better way to do that? The solution I was trying to was to create a tableLayout for each post via code...

Comment: No you don't have to create the layout in the code.
You can inflate the layout from a layout file and manipulate the contents of the TextView.
You could read about the ListView and for instance also about the BaseAdapter class.

Comment: Thats even easier I'm so dumb! >.<

This works fine:

LinearLayout main_post_container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_post_container);
View.inflate(MainActivity.this, R.layout.post_main, main_post_container); now I just have to find out how to handle that... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take into consideration that in such expressions you specify height and width in pixels, not in dp. Your picture may disappear just because it's wider or higher than your tablerow is (check your tablerow's layout parameters). Set your image's width and height to match_parent and check up how it feels.

Try using `imageView.requestLayout()` after you commit some changes in LayoutParams. This makes the View re-read the layout for changes.